# What cause packet loss on my network?

Tags: router, routing, ping, adsl, traceroute

This is my trace test from my PC to google.com

```
 1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2    23 ms    23 ms    23 ms  host-41.236.127.1.tedata.net [41.236.127.1]
  3    27 ms    27 ms    28 ms  10.38.74.201
  4    28 ms    28 ms    27 ms  10.36.23.162
  5    24 ms    25 ms    24 ms  10.38.24.153
  6    29 ms    28 ms    29 ms  10.37.123.225
  7    62 ms     *      112 ms  74.125.32.90
  8    62 ms    61 ms    59 ms  108.170.252.241
  9    59 ms    59 ms    61 ms  72.14.233.67
 10    60 ms    59 ms    60 ms  mrs08s03-in-f14.1e100.net [172.217.19.46]
```

I always have a 0 packet loss when do a ping test on any of the first 6 hops that are within the ISP network however when i do a ping test on any other ip outside the isp network.. for instance on google.com to on hop#7 i start to get some packet losses. till now it seems that my ISP has something wrong with there gateway but the strange thing is that using a computer outside my country (Google cloud virtual computer) i did a ping test on my router and as expected there were some packet loss however i did a ping on the second hop and there were 0 packet loss. My isp deny that they have any network issue from there side and they blame my router, what do you think is causing that issue?
PS: My connection is VDSL

and this is the WinMTR report

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                      WinMTR statistics                                   |
|                       Host              -   %  | Sent | Recv | Best | Avrg | Wrst | Last |
|------------------------------------------------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|                             192.168.1.1 -    0 |  869 |  869 |    0 |    0 |    7 |    1 |
|            host-41.236.127.1.tedata.net -    1 |  853 |  849 |   22 |   23 |   45 |   23 |
|                            10.38.74.169 -    1 |  845 |  839 |   23 |   24 |   81 |   24 |
|                            10.36.23.158 -    1 |  841 |  834 |   23 |   24 |   46 |   24 |
|                             10.36.21.33 -    2 |  810 |  795 |    0 |   28 |   75 |   27 |
|                            10.37.85.106 -    1 |  857 |  854 |   23 |   24 |   74 |   24 |
|        xe1-2-0.catania7.cat.seabone.net -    1 |  842 |  835 |   61 |   65 |  203 |   65 |
|         etrunk1.milano1.mil.seabone.net -   10 |  626 |  564 |   62 |   67 |  100 |   64 |
|                           72.14.209.236 -   33 |  382 |  259 |    0 |   69 |   99 |   67 |
|                          108.170.245.72 -   34 |  370 |  245 |    0 |   70 |   99 |   71 |
|                           64.233.175.51 -   31 |  392 |  272 |   66 |   69 |  199 |   68 |
|                            72.14.238.21 -   33 |  378 |  255 |   66 |   71 |  238 |   68 |
|                         108.170.252.241 -   31 |  390 |  270 |    0 |   70 |   96 |   70 |
|                            72.14.233.69 -   29 |  407 |  291 |    0 |   69 |   90 |   68 |
|               ham02s12-in-f14.1e100.net -   31 |  390 |  270 |    0 |   68 |  114 |   68 |
|________________________________________________|______|______|______|______|______|______|
   WinMTR v0.92 GPL V2 by Appnor MSP - Fully Managed Hosting & Cloud Provider
```

Thanks

Comment: Please use WinMTR (or similar which combines ping and traceroute) and post results - we need a lot more information before we.can deduce problems.

Comment: @davidgo i updated the question, please re-check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That traceroute strongly implies congestion (which could be caused by rate limiting or a bandwidth bottleneck or both) between the 7th and 8th hop - this is a problem/limit that is beyond your control and something the ISP is responsible for fixing (there are other possibilities, but they are unlikely and indicate you are not getting full Internet service - ie some traffic being blocked)

There also looks to be an unrelated (and comparatively minor) issue between your modem and ISP. That secondary issue - which presents as 1% packet loss could indicate a faulty modem or line issue and should be attended to as well, but this is not the primary source of your problem.

I would send this mtr to my provider and if they prevaricate and blame everyone but themselves shift to another one.